# Querying Postgres INHERITED tables directly

Tags: postgresql

Postgres allows you to create a table using inheritance. We have a design where we have 1400 tables that inherit from one main table. These tables are for each of our vendor's inventory.

When I want to query stock for a vendor, I just query the main table. When running `Explain`, the explanation says that it is going through all 1400 indexes and quite a few of the inherited tables. This causes the query to run very slowly. If I query only the vendor's stock table, I cut the query time to less than 50% of the time by querying the main table.

We have a join on another table that pulls identifiers for the vendor's partner vendors and we also want to query their stock. Example:

```
SELECT 
    (select m2.company from sup.members m2 where m2.id = u.id) as company,  
    u.id,
    u.item, 
    DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - u.datein::timestamp) AS daysinstock, 
    u.grade as condition, 
    u.stockno AS stocknumber, 
    u.ic, 
    CASE WHEN u.rprice > 0 THEN 
        u.rprice 
    ELSE 
        NULL 
    END AS price, 
    u.qty
FROM pub.net u 
LEFT JOIN sup.members m1 
    ON m1.id = u.id OR u.id = any(regexp_split_to_array(m1.partnerslist,',')) 
WHERE u.ic in ('01036') -- part to query
  AND m1.id = 'N40'     -- vendor to query
```

The n40_stock table has stock for the vendor with id = N40 and N40's partner vendors (partnerslist) are G01, G06, G21, K17, N49, V02, M16  so I would also want
to query the g01_stock, g06_stock, g21_stock, k17_stock, n49_stock, v02_stock, and m16_stock tables.

I know about the ONLY clause but is there away to modify this query to get the data from ONLY the specific inherited tables?

**Edit**
This decreases the time to under 800ms, but I'd like it less:

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT partnerslist as a FROM sup.members WHERE id = 'N40' 
) 
SELECT 
    (select m2.company from sup.members m2 where m2.id = u.id) as company,
    u.id,
    u.item, 
    DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - u.datein::timestamp) AS daysinstock, 
    u.grade as condition, 
    u.stockno AS stocknumber, 
    u.ic, 
    CASE WHEN u.rprice > 0 THEN 
        u.rprice 
    ELSE 
        NULL 
    END AS price, 
    u.qty
FROM pub.net u 
WHERE u.ic in ('01036') -- part to query
  AND u.id = any(regexp_split_to_array('N40,'||(select a from cte), ','))
```

I cannot retrieve the company from sup.members in the `cte` because I need the one from the u.id, which is different when the partner changes in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherited table lookups are based on the actual WHERE clause, which maps to the CHECK table constraint. Simply inheriting tables is not good enough.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Caveat, you can not use a dynamically created variables where the actual value is not implemented in the raw query. This results in a check of all inherited tables.

Comment: This is how the design was implemented. See my edited post.